# How do I go through an array for a input variable, and read the output variable

Tags: python

For example I have

```
commandz=[["yes","no"],["hi","hi"]]
async def handle_command(message):
    print('Noticed: ' + message.content)
    if message.content == 'tokenreset'+str(key):
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'code accepted')
    i = 0
    for i in commandz[i][0]:
        comm = commandz[i][0]
        if comm == message.content:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, commandz[i][1])
```

The error message I get is

```
C:\Users\trisimix>python "c:\Users\trisimix\compsocbot\main.py"
Found saved token in stored.py, use phrase tokenreset1424629785956179 to undo this.
Logged in as[198866998225141760]NOTAKOALAONACOMPUTERINVENEZUELA
--------
Noticed: hi
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\trisimix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\trisimix\compsocbot\main.py", line 34, in on_message
    await handle_command(message)
  File "c:\Users\trisimix\compsocbot\main.py", line 42, in handle_command
    comm = commandz[i]
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I am trying to get my program to check each command against an array using an if statement, then respond with the output.

Comment: `commandz[i][0]` is the string `"yes"`, so you are looping over "y","e" and "s". the first line into your for loop you try to access `commandz['y'][0]`

Comment: I'm trying to match a string against the string yes and hi, and return either no or hi if its a match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from line 6 of your code onwards (ie the for loop):

```
for comm in commandz:
    if comm[0] == message.content:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, comm[1])
```

The issue with your code is that you were looping over characters of a string (in `commandz[0][0]`), when what you actually wanted was to loop over the lists in your nested list (ie. `["yes","no"]` and `["hi","hi"]`, which is simply in `commandz`.

Note that I use the variable `comm` in as the lists within `commandz`, and not as the first index within those lists, ie `yes` and `hi` which I presume you intended to use it as